# Redirection to external URL with POST parameters from Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

For some subscription process, there is a requirement as follows :

1. User visits our website
2. For any subscription process, user click the relevant section that should redirect the view to specified external URL having POST parameters.
3. External party handles the subscription

It could be solved using `<form/>` defining the method=POST and putting all the required parameters in hidden fields.

But, we have CMS in place so changing the already existing view to support `<form/>` would be cumbersome.

I was hoping that there could be some solution that will allow in the following way:

1. User visits the page
2. User clicks the relevant section and sends the request to our internal  mapping (along with some ID).
3. Using that ID, will prepare the relevant payload and will redirect the view to external url along with that payload (using POST).

Please let me know for more information.

Comment: I need to know this too

Comment: @Kevin: Please refer the solution that I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) you can return s.th. like `redirect:http://myhost.com/some/arbitrary/path` in your controller. To do it dynamically, use the following

```
@RequestMapping("/redirect")
protected String redirect(@RequestParam("url") String url) 
{
    return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
}
```

Of course you can implement a special RedirectService on your own, but that should be simple.

It is not possible to send payload to another endpoint using a redirect. A redirect is a HTTP-Response with response code of 301,302,303,307,308 - each has a different intention (see [Wikipedia Statuscode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) for additional info). It is the responsibility of the client to decide what to do next - e.g. calling the new location with the same payload.

Comment: I need to send some payload over the endpoint URL while redirecting. With this approach, I won't be able to send the POST payload.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of redirects - see my edit above. You could call the desired endpoint with your server, but that's not a redirect

Comment: Yeah, redirect basically deals in GET request. But the integration that's needed to be done requires this feature. As the third party hosts some kind of consent page, so view needs to be returned to them. They need a lot of parameters that will be limited by GET method, so they expect the parameters in POST. 

I don't get direct method to make it working. I am looking for the workaround to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the way to perform the required use case.

In order to redirect the view with POST parameters, please refer the steps below

1) User clicks on the link.
2) Firstly redirect to user to internal mapping.(It would be an intermediate GET request before redirection to external endpoint).
Append all the required parameters to this endpoint.
3) Then transfer the view to intermittent form page populating all the fields in hidden tags.
4) Upon loading the page, submit this form to required destination using POST method.
In this way, we could hack this. I believe it's not a clean way, but if we have to do this, it could be done in this way.